# Dynamic path upload for Elfinder under symfony 6

Tags: symfony, configuration, elfinder

I'm using Symfony 6.3 and elfinder for image uploads. I have multiple users, and I want to configure an upload directory per user. The upload directory is generated via a service.

I tried putting the following configuration in the fm_elfinder.yaml file:

```
path: "@=service('App\\Service\\UploadPathService').getUploadPath()"
```

But it's not working.

I have the error "@=service('App\Service\UploadPathService').getUploadPath()" not exist

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Could you expand a bit on "not working"?

Comment: When I open Elfinder, I a the error that the directory ; @=service('App\\Service\\UploadPathService').getUploadPath()  not exist.